# Checking divisibility for Bool always results in false

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to check for leap years, which are "years either divisible by 400 or divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100." Removing one of the conditions still doesn't return a true on actual leap years. Only the z value in the tuple counts toward the divisibility but these conditions never return a True value for an actual leap year.

```
checkLeap :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
checkLeap (x,y,z)
  | z == 400 `mod` 1                   = True
  | z == 4 `mod` 1 && z /= 100 `mod` 1 = True
  | otherwise                          = False
```

Comment: Looks like some confusion here: `z == 400 \`mod\` 1` should be `z \`mod\` 400 == 0` surely? Similarly for the others. And why are you using a triple `(x,y,z)` when you only care about `z`?

Comment: Why does the function even take a tuple if it only needs the last element?

Comment: @Cubic It's probably as if there were a `type Date = (Int, Int, Int)` for month,day,year or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mod` is 0 when it's divisible, and it also doesn't go all the way on the end in Haskell. Try this instead:

```
checkLeap :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
checkLeap (x,y,z)
  | z `mod` 400 == 0                   = True
  | z `mod` 4 == 0 && z `mod` 100 /= 0 = True
  | otherwise                          = False
```

Comment: Damn it, I knew it was using `mod` wrong. Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot.